# How to update pyxb tree-like object in a loop?

Tags: python, reference, argparse

For my current project I'm reading a xml config file using [pyxb](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net). But it should be possible to override some of the settings by giving command line arguments (parsed using argparse).
To get more readable code, I would like to use an universal approach and define an update method. The parameter update has to use a try-catch-block, because pyxb does validate the new value on assignment (check string against pattern in this case).

Here is what I tried:

```
def override_setup(exp, args):
    for param, arg in [[exp.param1, args.param1], [exp.param2, args.param2]]:
        if arg is None:
            continue

        # this doesn't work, because param just references the string object referenced by exp.param1?
        try:                
            param = arg
        except Exception as e:
            print e

    # the following works
    exp.param1 = "stuff"
```

I'm creating a list containing the mapping of pyxb parameters to argparse command line arguments. I think this is where everything starts to get wrong.
I want some way to do this update using some kind of loop (so I don't need to repeat the try-catch-block for every element).
Unfortunately exp doesn't seem to be iterable. Each child of exp has a member `_getDiagnosticName()`, which returns a string I could use as a mapping to the arguments read by argparse.
I found an [article describing how to get a dict of the argparse results](http://parezcoydigo.wordpress.com/2012/08/04/from-argparse-to-dictionary-in-python-2-7/). So the mapping  (pyxb element -> argparse argument value) isn't a problem anymore. The iteration is the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching some more, I finally found the solution I was looking for: [setattr()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
def override_setup(exp, args):
    opts = vars(args)

    for param in ['param1', 'param2']:
        if opts[param] is None:
            continue

        try:
            setattr(exp, param, opts[param])
        except Exception as e:
            print e
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible, but a bit ugly solution. The main part is using [vars()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) (as in the article I referenced in my question...):

```
def override_setup(exp, args):
    exp_dict = vars(exp)
    opts = vars(args)

    # iterate over node
    for key in exp_dict:
        cur_param = None
        for param in ['param1', 'param2']:
            # ugly workaround
            # keys are like __{XML-Namespace-URI}_parent__param1
            if key.endswith(param):
                cur_param = param

        if not cur_param or opts[cur_param] is None:
            continue

        try:
            exp_dict[key] = opts[cur_param]
        except Exception as e:
            print e
```

In my case exp_dict contained at least 6 elements representing internal pyxb stuff you shouldn't touch. That's one reason I don't really like this solution. But it's the best I have for now.